# Is it illegal to temporarily park in front of my garage to wash my car if the townhouse association allows it and there are no posted signs?

Tags: california, is-x-legal

I live in a townhouse community and received a packet with the association rules when I moved here. It states that you may temporarily park in front of your garage for purposes such as loading, unloading, or washing cars. The streets are wide enough for a large vehicles to easily pass 2 large parked vehicles as there are only garage doors on either side and no driveways or sidewalks. All sidewalks are along the front of the townhomes while garages are at the rear. There are no signs posted anywhere prohibiting parking yet the police regularly ticket residents. Is this legal?

Comment: Do the tickets quote what laws are being violated?

Comment: Your question isn't really clear on where the garage, street and townhouse are facing. I've seen townhomes where the garages face an alley, not a street which is what your situation sounds like, but could use clarification. Although Rick's question is more important.

Comment: It's unlikely that the HOA has the authority to override city or county ordinances. So just because the HOA says they allow it doesn't make it legal. You'll have to check with whatever authority is issuing the fines and possibly even go as far as taking the matter to court for a judge to decide. Your HOA's position on the matter is in all likelihood irrelevant.

Comment: HOAs don't create laws and don't have ticketing authority.  They can, however, establish rules and enforce those rules through assessments and liens.  So if the local LE department is issuing tickets, they would be for a violation of an actual law or regulation.  Parking is certainly in a local government's jurisdiction.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible from your description to tell where the roads and driveways are. [CVC 22500 ff](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displayText.xhtml?lawCode=VEH&division=11.&title=&part=&chapter=9.&article=) gives some general rules that apply across the state, regarding parking. It *is* illegal to park in front of a driveway, and one typically enters a garage via a driveway, so parking in front of a garage is illegal. If the HOA says it is legal, they may be over-stepping their authority. Also, your municipality is allowed to impose parking restrictions. It is reasonably likely that these tickets are being given legally, though if you feel that the police are making a legal error, you could pursue the matter in court – perhaps they have misinterpreted the law or are not in possession of all of the facts.

Answer (score 0):

Washing your car on the street is [prohibited](https://codelibrary.amlegal.com/codes/los_angeles/latest/lamc/0-0-0-166764) in Los Angeles, probably other California counties or cities, too.

In addition, it's discouraged by water utilities because the dirty water goes down storm drains (plus, of course, the issue of the recent drought).

Comment: Downvoters care to leave a comment? Or just unhappy about car washing?

Comment: Not my DV, but you might want to read your link, especially the bit beginning with "*unless*..."